# drawing a rhombus/diamond on processing

Tags: static, processing, drawing

I am a absolute beginner in Processing-language and I am struggling with a little Task.

my task is to create a drawing in which one rhombus is in each square, but then vice versa a square in the superimposed rhombus.

I looked up on Processing References and found some usefull Functions, but I am struggling with the Rhombus shape.

Any hint would be good, as I still try to learn it myself

Comment: It's all math and coordinates. What is it that puzzles you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a simple math problem, you just have to calculate the 4 positions of your shapes depending on the shape you want to put inside, I made here is an example on how to fit a diamond inside a square:

```
float x,y; //x,y coordinate of the square
float w;  //width of the square

void setup() {

  size(500,500);

 //initializing the coordinates of the square to a random position
  x=random(100,300);
  y=random(100,300);
  w=random(50,300);

}

void draw() {

 //draw black background
 background(0);
 
 //setting up the color and stroke of the shapes
 stroke(255);
 strokeWeight(3);
 noFill();
 
 //drawing the rectangle
 rect(x,y,w,w);
 
 //drawing the diamond inside
 //first point is the middle of the upper side
 float x1= (x+(x+w))/2; 
 float y1= y; 
 
 //second point is the middle of the right side
 float x2= x+w; 
 float y2= (y+(y+w))/2; 
 
 //third point is the middle of the lower side
 float x3= x1; 
 float y3= y+w; 
 
 //forth point is the middle of the left side
 float x4= x; 
 float y4= y2; 
 
 //drawing the diamond using those four points
 quad(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4);

}
```